# Chrome / IE, AngularJS, and Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, angularjs

I'm building a web app in AngularJS that's supposed to be distributable via CDs, but I've hit a brick wall with the same origin policy of Chrome and IE, respectively:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///xxx. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Is there any way I can bypass this in code or by some other means?

Comment: This is an XSS issue and there are ton of answers already on SO.

Comment: not in this context. the app will get distributed, and others will use it on their local fs. the solution has to work for everybody, so that no one will need to start up their browsers with parameters manually

Comment: Could you add shortcut icons on the CD containing the parameters to open the browser?

Comment: You could also put some executable/script that will detect the default browser of the user and launch it with the corresponding parameters.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions! i'll add that i've found a workaround of sorts and if it works, i'll post an update - http://goo.gl/Xh9fZ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I went with is to define all templates inline in the `index.html` file via the `<script
type="text/ng-template">` directive like this:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/template.html">
     <h1>I'm the content</h1>
</script>
<ng-include src="/template.html"></ng-include>
```

Comment: This is a great suggestion and solved my problem where partials could not be hosted on the same domain as the JS files. Take a look at this: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:script

Answer (score 1):

yes you can by 
`delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];`

before the request